# Impute missing data of a single variable using the slope of a linear regression of another variable in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, missing-data

Here is an extract of my dataset (df8) which contains time series from 2000 to 2018 for 194 countries.

```
   iso3   year   anc4 median
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 BIH    2000 NA      0.739
 2 BIH    2001 NA      0.746
 3 BIH    2002 NA      0.763
 4 BIH    2003 NA      0.778
 5 BIH    2004 NA      0.842
 6 BIH    2005 NA      0.801
 7 BIH    2006 NA      0.819
 8 BIH    2007 NA      0.841
 9 BIH    2008 NA      0.845
10 BIH    2009 NA      0.840
11 BIH    2010  0.842  0.856
12 BIH    2011 NA      0.873
13 BIH    2012 NA      0.867
14 BIH    2013 NA      0.889
15 BIH    2014 NA      0.879
16 BIH    2015 NA      0.883
17 BIH    2016 NA      0.854
18 BIH    2017 NA      0.891
19 BIH    2018 NA      0.920
20 BWA    2000 NA      0.739
21 BWA    2001 NA      0.746
22 BWA    2002 NA      0.763
23 BWA    2003 NA      0.778
24 BWA    2004 NA      0.842
25 BWA    2005 NA      0.801
26 BWA    2006  0.733  0.819
27 BWA    2007 NA      0.841
28 BWA    2008 NA      0.845
29 BWA    2009 NA      0.840
30 BWA    2010 NA      0.856
31 BWA    2011 NA      0.873
32 BWA    2012 NA      0.867
33 BWA    2013 NA      0.889
34 BWA    2014 NA      0.879
35 BWA    2015 NA      0.883
36 BWA    2016 NA      0.854
37 BWA    2017 NA      0.891
38 BWA    2018 NA      0.920
```

What I would like to do is to impute missing data for variable anc4, using the slope of a linear regression based on regional medians (median). I would like to do that at the country level as each country do not pertain to the same region.

This is what I have tried..

```
df_model <-  df8

predictions <- vector()

for(i in unique(df_model$iso3)) {
  temp <- df_model[df_model[,2]==i,]
  predictions <- c(predictions,predict(lm(median~year,temp),df8[is.na(df8$anc4) & df8$iso3==i,]))
}

df8[is.na(df8$anc4),]$anc4 <- predictions
```

I used the code I have been using when imputing missing anc4 data using a linear regression of observed anc4 data points and tried to adapt that using medians..but did not quite work!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Of note, `lm(median~year+iso3, data=df_model) %>% summary` seems to say that the region is not very relevant here, but that may be example-bound.

Comment: I just want to draw a line based on median values and retrieve the slope and use it to impute missing data for the country..

Comment: In your example, you have only 1 non-missing value per region, will this always be the case? Otherwise, you might want to describe a little more what should happen when there are several, as the slope might not connect those perfectly.

Comment: 1/ When a country do not have any data, we impute with regional medians. 2/ When a country has at least 2 data points, we impute using linear regression based on observed data in the country. 3/ But when a country only has one data point, we need to use the slope of a linear regression based on regional medians. I have already done the first two, now I have to do the third one, so it means that all data are already imputed for the other countries. The only countries where no data have been imputed are those with only one data point (per country, not per region).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last comment made your question clear: you get the slope from the linear regression on the medians and you get the intercept from the only non-missing value.

However, there was a rather serious flaw in your code: you should never grow a vector inside a `for` loop. Use `*apply` functions, or even better use `*map` functions from the `purrr` package. If you have a very good reason to use a `for` loop, at least preallocate its size.

Since you get the intercept from outside the model, you cannot use `predict` here. Fortunately, it is rather simple to predict manually when using a linear model.

Here is my solution using the `dplyr` syntax. If you are not familiar with it, I urge you to read about it (for instance [there](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/))

```
x=df_model %>% 
  group_by(iso3) %>% 
  mutate(
    slope=lm(median~year)$coefficients["year"],
    intercept=anc4[!is.na(anc4)]-slope*year[!is.na(anc4)],
    anc4_imput = intercept+year*slope,
    anc4_error = anc4-anc4_imput,
  )


x
#> # A tibble: 38 x 8
#> # Groups:   iso3 [2]
#>    iso3   year  anc4 median   slope intercept anc4_imput anc4_error
#>    <fct> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 BIH    2000    NA  0.739 0.00844     -16.1      0.758         NA
#>  2 BIH    2001    NA  0.746 0.00844     -16.1      0.766         NA
#>  3 BIH    2002    NA  0.763 0.00844     -16.1      0.774         NA
#>  4 BIH    2003    NA  0.778 0.00844     -16.1      0.783         NA
#>  5 BIH    2004    NA  0.842 0.00844     -16.1      0.791         NA
#>  6 BIH    2005    NA  0.801 0.00844     -16.1      0.800         NA
#>  7 BIH    2006    NA  0.819 0.00844     -16.1      0.808         NA
#>  8 BIH    2007    NA  0.841 0.00844     -16.1      0.817         NA
#>  9 BIH    2008    NA  0.845 0.00844     -16.1      0.825         NA
#> 10 BIH    2009    NA  0.84  0.00844     -16.1      0.834         NA
#> # ... with 28 more rows

#error is negligible 
x %>% filter(!is.na(anc4))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#> # Groups:   iso3 [2]
#>   iso3   year   anc4 median   slope intercept anc4_imput anc4_error
#>   <fct> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 BIH    2010  0.842  0.856 0.00844    -16.1       0.842   1.22e-15
#> 2 BWA    2006 10.7   10.8   0.00844     -6.20     10.7     0.

#Created on 2020-06-12 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: That is rather simple! I have not thought about it. I know the package, wonderful! Thank you so much.